# How to deploy Azure Website with Virtual Application using VSO Continuous Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a Microsoft Azure Website and a virtual application running under it that I have configured. I am able to deploy both the main web application and the virtual application successfully by right clicking on each project and selecting publish. The main web application deploys to the site root, and my virtual application deploys to its sub directory (in this case it's /Api).

We keep our code under source control in Visual Studio Online which you can connect to an Azure website for continuous deployment. However, when I run the build for the virtual application (Api) it deploys it to the root of the site and not to /Api.

I have a number of other cloud services and websites utilizing CD already. It's the virtual application part that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box deployment build only deploys a single application. In this case your site.

To deploy multiple applications you need to use the DefaultTemplate.12.xaml and create a PowerShell to do your deployment in the post-test script step.

This problem will be fixed by a new build system being developed by MSFT...